# Project App.Droid cannot build using TargetFrameworkVersion v8.1 because it is not supported

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, target-framework

Having this issue when trying to build Xamarin.Android project (Xamarin.Forms)

**Project App.Droid cannot build using TargetFrameworkVersion v8.1 because it is not supported. Please change your Xamarin.Android project to target an API version that is supported.**

[image]

How do I resolve this issue?
I think I have installed SDKs I need, screenshot is here

[image]

Comment: What version of Xamarin.Android are you using? Secondly, you are using a pretty old version of SDK Manager, have you updated your SDK tooling recently?

Comment: Add this as answer and I'll accept it.  Yes, after updating my VS2017 v.15.35 to v.15.7.5, I was able to install newer Android SDKs (VS prompted me for that) and all went well after that, so yes, tooling seem to be an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading my VS2017 v.15.3.5 to v.15.7.5, I was able to install newer Android SDKs and tooling and all went well after that.